# Перестает работать скрол навигация на jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Здравствуйте. Столкнулся с такой проблемой , что именно у меня в гугле скрипт на скролл по навигации работает нормально, как на локалке, так и на обычном сервере, но в других браузерах и у других пользователей полностью перестает работать данный скролл , с чем это может быть связанно?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('a[href^="#"]').click(function(){
    var el = $(this).attr('href');
    $('body').animate({
     scrollTop: $(el).offset().top}, 1500);
     return false;
    });
  });
```

Comment: Он не скролится а сразу переходит по ссылке? Если да то нужен перехват event.

Comment: Нет , при нажатие просто ничего не происходит

Comment: А если после `$('a[href^="#"]').click(function(){` добавить `console.log('click');` отрабатывает код? Возможно он не валиден, т.к. не хватает закрывающей скобки в конце js

Comment: Тоже не помогает , проблема то в том , что у меня на компе в хроме всё отлично работает , но если с ноута пытаюсь нажимать на кнопки , то он не реагирует, и если пытаюсь в фаерфоксе покликать тоже ничего не работает

Comment: Консоль что то выдает? Если нет, проверьте линки на js или заменить селектор отбора на простой a для проверки

Comment: Да консоль выдает "click" в логе

Comment: `preventDefault` не пробовали? `$('a[href^="#"]').click(function(e){e.preventDefault(); //rest of the code })`

Comment: Тоже не помогает

Comment: а вместе с `stopPropagation`? `$('a[href^="#"]').click(function(e){e.preventDefault(); e.stopPropagation(); //rest of the code })`

Comment: Тоже ничего не меняется , давайте дам ссылку на сайт , может понятнее будет? leonxweb.ru

Comment: А что выдаст `console.log($(el).offset().top);` после var

Comment: 800.0000122189522 ,
1554.4000244140625 , 
2354.4000244140625 ,
3154.39990234375 ,
3954.39990234375
Примерно такие значения у себя на компе на локалке

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Замените `$('body').animate({` на `$('html,body').animate({` Проверил у Вас на сайте, работает.

Comment: Спасибо большое , всё заработало)